How can I find fourier series of periodic function without replacing A, T with numbers?
How can  I find fourier series?
A = 1,
T = $\pi$
If we substitute A, T with numbers (A = 1,
T = $\pi$), this code works perfectly.
f[t_] := Module[{tMod}, tMod = Mod[t + T/2, T] - T/2;
  Which[-T/2 < tMod < 0, A, 0 < tMod < T/2, 0]]
FourierSeries[f[t], t, 3]


I think your use of FourierSeries is wrong. F.S. by default assumes the period is 2*Pi, because the default FourierParameters is {1,1}.
your function, the way you defined it, has period Pi. F.S. does not know that. So you have to tell it the period of your function by changing FourierParameters.
To do what you want, i.e. keep A and T symbolic, you can try this
ClearAll[T,A,f,t];
f[t_, T_, A_] := Piecewise[{{A, -T/2 < t < 0}, {0, 0 < t < T/2}}]
r = FourierSeries[f[t, T, A], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2*Pi/T}]


Now you can plugin any value for T and A
 r/.{A->1,T->Pi}


Now to use what you did, you need to modify the FourierParameters like this
A0=1;T0=Pi;
g[t_]:=Module[{tMod},tMod=Mod[t+T0/2,T0]-T0/2;
Which[-T0/2<tMod<0,A0,0<tMod<T0/2,0]]
FourierSeries[g[t],t,3,FourierParameters->{1,2*Pi/T0}]


Which is the same as before.

Is there a way to convert it to trig form?

Yes. use ExpToTrig
r /. {A -> 1, T -> Pi}
ExpToTrig[%]



Is there a way to convert it  to trig form?

@kile yes. Updated.

ClearAll[T, A, f, t]; f[t_, T_, A_] := Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= t < T/2}, {A, T/2 <= t < T}}] r = FourierSeries[f[t, T, A], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2*Pi/T},    Assumptions -> 0 < T] FullSimplify[r] ExpToTrig[r]
`
This output 0. What's wrong here?
